# Gradle - dont create parent build in multi module project

Tags: java, build, gradle

I have project with structure like this:

```
┌project
│
├── build.gradle
├── module 1
│    │
│    ├── build.gradle
│    ├── module 1.1
│    └── module 1.2
│  
└── module 2
     │
     ├── build.gradle
     ├── module 2.1
     └── module 2.2
```

My problem is that I have builds created for project, module 1 and module 2. But I do not need them, I only need builds from module 1.1, 1.2, 2.1 and 2.2.

In submodules build.gradle:

```
project(":modules 1") {
    ext.buildables = [
            project(':modules-1:modules.1.1'),
            project(':modules-1:modules.1.2')]    
}

project(":modules-1:modules.1.1") {

    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}
```

In root build.gradle:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6
}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Edit:

After running gradle build, there is follwoing directory structure:

```
┌project
│
├── build.gradle
├── build (not wanted)
├── module 1
│    │
│    ├── build (not wanted)
│    ├── build.gradle
│    ├── module 1.1
|    |    |
│    |    └── build
│    └── module 1.2
|         |
│         └── build
│  
└── module 2
     │
     ├── build (not wanted)
     ├── build.gradle
     ├── module 2.1
     |    |
     |    └── build
     └── module 2.2
          |
          └── build
```

How to get rid of these not wanted folders, they all have jars with size of 1kb inside.

Comment: For me this question is unclear.

Comment: @Opal see if it is more understable now

Comment: Yes it's much better now. Maybe this link will help You: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_skip_jar_when_empty_manifest_on ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Opal for providing link to [this discussion](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-skip-jar-when-empty-manifest-only/3276).

Added following to `allprojects`, which skips empty jars.

```
jar {
    onlyIf { !sourceSets.main.allSource.files.isEmpty() }
}
```

Comment: Another option is to delete the root-level build directory when the build is finished. This was the solution I had to use, because I have shared classes between all of the submodules that I keep in the parent module source, but the build was making a JAR for the parent module, which shouldn't exist. The answer is to make the parent `build.gradle` contain this: `gradle.buildFinished { project.buildDir.deleteDir() }`. See this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52556528/2386514