# gradle: disable creation of the build folder at root in multi-projects application

Tags: gradle, build

My `gradle` project is a `multi-project` structure. It consists of two subprojects. My `build.gradle` in root project as following:

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'eclipse'
}

subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

  publishing {
    repositories {
      maven {
        name 'myMaven'
        def suffix = project.version.endsWith("SNAPSHOT") ? "snapshots" : "releases"
        url baseUrl + suffix
      }
    }

    publications {
      core(MavenPublication) {
        artifactId project.name
        artifact jar
      }
    }
  }
}

project(':projectA') {
  ext {
    sharedManifest = manifest {
      attributes("Implementation-Title": project.name,
                 "Implementation-Version": 1.0 )
    }
  }
  jar {
    manifest = project.manifest {
      from sharedManifest
    }
  }
}

project('projectB') {
  ext {
    sharedManifest = manifest {
      attributes("Implementation-Title": project.name,
                 "Implementation-Version": 2.0 )
    }
  }
  jar {
    manifest = project.manifest {
      from sharedManifest
    }
  }
}
```

After `gradle build`, I got three build folders. one at the root directory and other two in the respective subprojects. The root project is just an empty folder without any source code, it is just a multi-project container.

Now I need to eliminate the creation of root build folder since it is of no use. I search on the net and in the gradle docs/forum but did not get any hit.

Is there any way so that gradle stop creating build folder at root level?

Comment: Why do you care about that folder? Simply exclude it from your version control and hide it in your IDE and you are good to go.

Comment: It is already excluded. The reason of above is that we don't want that folder to be created in bamboo server.

Comment: Would deleting the folder after creation solve ur problem?

Comment: What is in the root `build` folder after a build ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Who is responsible for the `build` dir creation ?

[According to Mark Vieira](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/at-what-point-in-the-gradle-lifecycle-is-the-build-folder-created-and-how-should-a-custom-task-ensure-that-it-has-already-happened/4217/2), a Gradle core dev, each task is responsible for the creation of the ouput dir as long as  it creates output.

So basically, it your root project does have a `build` dir, it means it's not empty and something is deliberately writing into it.

In my job, I'm managing a big project constituted by a root project, which handles many `.gradle` files, settings files etc. and many subprojects with the actual code. When I run `gradle clean build`, all subprojects get their own `build` dir with libs, binaries etc. but the root project does not end up with any `build` dir because no task whatsoever writes output in the root `build` dir.

### What can I do to remove the root `build` dir, whatever task creating it ?

Just set up a `buildFinished` hook **only for the root project**

```
gradle.buildFinished {
    project.buildDir.deleteDir()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I have a more correct solution, without having to delete the `/build` folder after creation :)

As we know, when we append some plugins to our gradle project, as a rule it adds some tasks to gradle lifecycle. So you could disable tasks, that create `/build` folder.

With only `java` plugin, you could disable `build` and `jar` tasks.

To do this, add to root `build.gradle` file this lines:

```
jar.enabled = false
build.enabled = false
```

If you have a `org.springframework.boot` plugin, disable another two tasks:

```
bootJar.enabled = false
bootJarMainClassName.enabled = false
```